# Move option between two selects with only one option

Tags: jquery, html

Trying to move `option`-tags between to `select` lists.

Html:

```
<select name="lista" id="lista" multiple="multiple">
     <option value="1">a</option>
     <option value="2">b</option>
     <option value="3">c</option>
     <option value="4">d</option>
</select>

<select id="listb" name="listb[]" multiple="multiple"></select>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#lista")
    .change(function() {
        $("#lista option:selected").each(function() {
            $(this).remove().appendTo('#listb').prop("selected", "selected");
        });
    })
    .trigger("change");

$("#listb")
    .change(function() {
        $("#listb option:selected").each(function() {
            $(this).remove().appendTo('#lista').prop("selected", "");
        });
    })
    .trigger("change");
```

Working great, if I move many items from ListA to ListB. But when there's only one item in ListB, I can't get it back to ListA because I found no way the trigger a `change`-event. How could I do this?

Comment: `$("#listb").on("change click", handler)` Does it fix your issue? http://jsfiddle.net/PV53v/2  FYI, using appendTo(), we don't need to remove element before, this will just move the element

Comment: Thx for the hint with the appendTo()!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the selectedIndex of the selects to -1, it should trigger the change event when the item is selected.

```
$('#listb').prop('selectedIndex', -1);
```